# Azure API Management with Function App - not showing all functions

Tags: azure-functions, azure-api-management

I have an Azure Functions App that has about 15 functions (API Calls).  The project uses Swashbuckle.  When I go to the portal, select the function app, and select "Functions" I can see all 15 functions.  When I import the Function App into Azure API Management, it only sees the "Swagger" and "SwaggerUI" functions - the rest are missing.

I've looked through the configuration of the function and azure API management but I cant find an answer.  Any help appreciated.

[image]

Comment: what type of azure functions you are importing ? 
You can import only Functions that are based off HTTP trigger and have the authorization level setting set to Anonymous or Function.

Comment: Could you please share a screenshot for the `Functions` tab page of your function app ?

Comment: Are you sure other functions is based on httptrigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as mentioned, you need to check on 2 points

1. You can import only Functions that are based off HTTP trigger
2. Ensure the authorization level setting set to Anonymous or Function

you can accepted this an answer to your question, Cheer !

Answer (score 0):

> When I go to the portal, select the function app, and select
> "Functions" I can see all 15 functions. When I import the Function App
> into Azure API Management, it only sees the "Swagger" and "SwaggerUI"
> functions - the rest are missing.

As Turbot says, not all of the function will be loaded. Please make sure your function is based on httptrigger instead of other triggers.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you - the authorization level was set to "Admin" on the other functions.  Changing it to "Function" solved the problem!